# How do I COUNT the same email being used, but a different domain in this MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

I have three fields: clean_email, email, and email_domain

**Clean email:** is the information before the domain. So if an email was dataguy@yahoo.com, this field would just say dataguy

**Email** is the whole email: dataguy@yahoo.com

**email_domain** is just the domain: yahoo.com

I am needing to Count the number clean emails that have different domains. We are noticing that some emails may be dataguy@yahoo.com, dataguy@hotmail.com, or dataguy@outlook.com. You notice the email is the same, but the domain is different, so we are trying to recognize when this happens. The total count of domains for this individual would be 3, and I need those specific domains listed out.

My query currently is:

```sql
SELECT clean_email, email, COUNT(DISTINCT email_domain)
    FROM email
    GROUP BY clean_email, email
```

I have tried using `COUNT` in multiple ways, but it's not returning what I need. It usually returns 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substring_index()`:

```
SELECT substring_index(email, '@', 1) as clean_email,
       COUNT(DISTINCT substring_index(email, '@', -1))
FROM email
GROUP BY clean_email;
```

EDIT:

If you want the domains, then use `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT substring_index(email, '@', 1) as clean_email,
       COUNT(DISTINCT substring_index(email, '@', -1)),
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT substring_index(email, '@', -1))
FROM email
GROUP BY clean_email
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT substring_index(email, '@', -1)) > 1;
```

Comment: This was very helpful, although it's a bit off of what I need.

An expected output would be:

clean_email: | domain | how many different domains used with this clean_email~~~~



dataguy       yahoo.com    dataguy@yahoo.com    4

and then 3 other rows repeating showing the exact same thing, but the domain name being different.

Comment: @JumpJ . . . That is what this now does (and the original intention).  I types `01` rather than `-1` in the second `substring_index()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff love your compact code :-) but clean_email's not supposed to contain an @. It's just the part before the @

Comment: @davmos . . . That is what this does.

Comment: See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/492983/4), then I think the OP wants the domain in the results also

Comment: @davmos . . . Sample data and desired results are so helpful.  I do see that the question says that it wants the domains.

Comment: :-) yeah.. praise SQL Fiddle!... but the substring_index() call should be on `email`... that was the reason for my first comment

Answer (score 0):

How about a [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)?...

```
WITH multiple_domain AS
(
    SELECT 
        clean_email,
        COUNT(*) AS domain_count
    FROM email
    GROUP BY clean_email
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT 
    e.clean_email,
    e.email_domain,
    md.domain_count
FROM email AS e
JOIN multiple_domain AS md ON md.clean_email = e.clean_email
ORDER BY e.email;
```

Or if not yet on MySQL 8.0, a derived table does the same job...

```
SELECT 
    e.clean_email,
    e.email_domain,
    md.domain_count
FROM email AS e
JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        clean_email,
        COUNT(*) AS domain_count
    FROM email
    GROUP BY clean_email
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS md ON md.clean_email = e.clean_email
ORDER BY e.email;
```

[Click here to have a play with it on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/492983/2)